# Is multipart/form-data available for apex @RestResource classes

Tags: apex, apexrest, restresource

I have a class that retrieves a file in binary code from an external webservice call to our Salesforce and generates a file but now they want to change it to `multipart/form-data`.

I've been reading the documentation but I'm not finding anything related to this topic apart from some comments saying that this is not possible right now in apex.

Is there a way to achieve this or it's not possible?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely [**not** possible at this time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm).

> Apex REST currently doesn't support requests of Content-Type multipart/form-data.

Unfortunately, you'd have to go about it a different way, such as encoding the file as base64 and then putting it into an XML/JSON payload.